# Basic binary conversion fails on PIC

Tags: pic, mikroc

I have the following code, converting dec. to binary (stored as an int) and it runs just fine in C::B :

```
 for(i=0;i<8;i++)
   {
    carry = start_value%2;
    tab[bla] = carry;
    bla++;
    start_value = start_value/2;
   }

for(i=bla; i>0; i--)
       {
       binary = binary + tab[i]*pow(10,i);
       }
```

But when I try to do the same on a PIC18F4550 with MikroC it just fails !
I have included 'pow' and respected the declarations for the variables I use. No matter what, the output is wrong (-62053 instead of 110110 for instance).

Thanks for taking a look into it :)
Have a nice day

Comment: Could you provide a compilable example with variable declarations and showing how the output is done, please ?

Comment: Different sizeof(int) on PIC ?

Answer (score 0):

You should start the second loop from `i = bla - 1` since it was incremented one more time than there binary digits. Also it could be that `tab[]` isn't initialized to 0.

And the second loop shall comprise the first tab element : tab[0] :

```
for(i = bla - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    binary += tab[i] * pow(10, i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the size of an `int` type (`sizeof(int)`) for this PIC architecture. For example, if an `int` is 16 bit, the maximum value it can hold is 65535 (for an `unsigned int`) or from -32768 to 32767 (for an `int`). Probably the problem is that the value you are calculating is too big for the type you are using.

Answer (score 0):

To get a decimal value from an array of binary digits, you have to multiply them by the appropriate powers of 2, not of 10.  Assuming pow() is what it appears to be, pow(base, exponent), you need to use pow(2,i) instead.

Answer (score 0):

jmpcm :
An int is 16 bits (2 bytes) on my PIC18F.
But the problem is that the code runs fine on my computer but not on the PIC, whereas variables I use have the same size.

philippe :
I have a feeling you might be right about the table not being cleared ! Can't test it yet though.

Jeanne Pindar :
No. I am storing an array of bits that I need to interact with in an int (need to save RAM space), so we're still working base10 on final storing.

All :
I managed my way out of it with a structure for which I defined all the bits :

```
struct {
unsigned int bit0: 1;
unsigned int bit1: 1;
...
```

So I can store 1 bit in a group of 8 bits and treat it as an int in main calculations and access it in a Nx1 matrix.

Thanks for your help nonetheless !

Comment: this is not an answer to your question. This should have been posted as individual comment to each responses. You can edit your question, too. See the faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask